# org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 192.168.0.104:8443 [/192.168.0.104] failed: connect timed out

Tags: java, json, spring, apache, web-services

I have one java spring mvc application which has api services and also we use ssl for the website. The api reads json and gives output as json. Without https protocol in url everything works fine.

'm trying to consume the webservice by calling https://example.com/appname/apiurl with post parameters as  json.

Here is the api method

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
     String json = "";
     try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8443);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Client said :" + br.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));

    if (br != null) {
        json = br.readLine();

    }

    // 2. initiate jackson mapper
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    anulomtrnstatus anulompbean = null;
    // 3. Convert received JSON to Article
    try {
        anulompbean = mapper.readValue(json, beanclass.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Here is the error console.

org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 192.168.0.104:8443 [/192.168.0.104] failed: connect timed out

Comment: ( I have used https://example.com/ for https://192.168.0.104:8443/ ) here.

Comment: Can u telnet directly to that service? telnet example.com 8443?

Comment: Yes. in test environment if I use http://example.com/appname/resturl then everything works fine. Hope somewhere I need to add trustStore to call the ssl api.

Comment: Your server is bound to 8443, and why are you tring to call 443 port. Your correct URL should be  https://example.com:8443/appname/apiurl Also you are getting a connection timeout so its not a SSL issue.